# Is Adam's Peak a sacred place for Muslims?

Tags: prophet-adam

Adam's Peak is a tall conical mountain located in central Sri Lanka. Muslims in all over the world go to Adam's Peak. Is Adam's Peak a sacred place for Muslims?

Answer (score 2):

> Is Adam's Peak a sacred place for Muslims?

No, it has no religious significance in Islam. There are no hadiths (Islamic tradition) or verse of the Qur'an that says anything about it.

OP's claim that "Muslims in all over the world go to Adam's Peak." is questionable. What evidence do you have for this? And even if that's true, it won't make the so called Adam's Peak a sacred place for Muslims (cause Islamic scriptures doesn't say anything about it being sacred).

Answer (score 0):

By deeming that the correctness of that place is confirmed, it might be remarked that:

It is considered as a holy place by itself as a related place to Adam (as a prophet of Allah), but it doesn't seem to be any related narration about that (to the best of my knowledge). So, it would be nice if they use that part by reciting Quran and Dua (as a place which a prophet of Allah...), but:

It ought not to be done as if it is a narrated saint place... in order to prevent the Bid'ah (innovation) as a haram practice.

Answer (score 0):

I'm from Sri Lanka and I've seen Muslims say the place is related to them due to its English name. That name was given by foreigners in [colonial times](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_Ceylon). But in the local language ([Sinhala](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinhalese_language)) Sri Lankans call it "Siri padaya," or "samanala kanda," which don't show any relation with Adam. But in written literature there is much evidence that this place has Buddha's footprint. So the idea that this place has Adam's footprint is a myth.

Comment: Written literature doesn't prove anything. They are just opinions of the writers unless they provide scientific evidence for the claims.